# How can I read my html file inside JavaScript file using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code. Here I declared one variable.

```
<script src="index.js">
    var str = {{:stringVar:}};
</script>
```

This is my JavaScript file content. Here if my condition satisfies my HTML file variable have to get my javascript file variable and it must be replaced.

```
var hello='gettingvalue from browser'
if(hello ='master'){
 var changestr ='new asp key for mas';
 }
 else{
 var changestr ='new asp key for dev'
 }
```

How can I get my HTML file variable into js file?

Comment: Try the [native query selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

**you can use ajax to read your HTML file.**

**first read your HTML file then replace your new variable then write it into html file**

**Here I gave code to read html file inside JS file and replace that variable**

```js
if(true){
 var aspkey = 'key for master';
    var ajax = new ej.base.Ajax('./src/template.html', 'GET', true);
    ajax.send().then(function (result) {
        var f = result;
        var newstr = f.replace(/{{:stringVar:}}/, aspkey)
    });
    }
  else{
  var aspkey = 'key for dev';
    var ajax = new ej.base.Ajax('./src/template.html', 'GET', true);
    ajax.send().then(function (result) {
        var f = result;
        var newstr = f.replace(/{{:stringVar:}}/, aspkey)
    });
    }
```

**Finally you have to write this into your  HTML file**

Comment: i tried it. worked thanks. but faced some problems but cleared it

Answer (score 0):

You could get HTML file content using jquery ajax call as follows

```
$.get("PATH_TO_HTML_FILE", function(fileText){
  console.log(fileText)
});
```

Comment: how it will work?. it just read html file .  it cant replace older variable

Comment: i am also having same doubts?

Comment: Get fileText in the global variable and replace your older variable with global variable value.